# want to make a live clock

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I want to make a live clock where I set the datetime from the API. Like if my API date is "2021-05-06T02:30:00.4660267" then the clock start the time from this datetime. This function will set the time but not working like a live clock.

I am using this code.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getCurrentTime("2021-05-06T02:30:00.4660267");
}



getCurrentTime = (type: string) => {
    let datePart = type.toString().split("T");
    let date = new Date(type);
    let hour = date.getHours();
    let min = date.getMinutes();
    let sec = date.getSeconds();
    
    let midday = "AM";
    midday = hour >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM"; 
    hour =
      hour == 0
        ? 12
        : hour > 12
        ? hour - 12
        : hour;

   
    if (Number(hour) < 10) {
      hour = `0${hour}`;
    }
    if (Number(min) < 10) {
      min = `0${min}`;
    }
    if (Number(sec) < 10) {
      sec = `0${sec}`;
    }

    let currentTime =
    hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + midday;
    this.setState({ currTime: currentTime });
    curntTickTime = datePart[0] + "T" + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    var t = setTimeout(this.againCall, 1000); 
  };

againCall = () => {
   this.getCurrentTime(curntTickTime);
  };
```

Comment: Why should `curntTickTime` be known inside `againCall`? You declared that in the local scope of `getCurrentTime` with `let`.

Comment: I want to set the next time in 'curntTickTime', So that the next time function call set the +1 second. @CBroe

Comment: @CBroe This  variable is declared as globally. So, when the getCurrentTime is called then it will set the next tick to this variable and when againCall is called it will use this variable value. So, in this way I except it to work.

Comment: My bad, it is `currentTime` that is locally declared with `let´. Okay, so you will have to do some debugging then … What have you done so far in that regard?